# can not autowire JobLauncher, always returns null

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, job-scheduling

i tried to link every job with a thread so i can launch multiple jobs in the same time with different cron value but the jobLauncher always gets null.

i tried to create jobLauncher as a bean in configuartion class but it never worked.

```
@Component
public class MyTask extends Thread {

   @Autowired
   private ApplicationContext context;

   @Autowired
   private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

   @Autowired
   private Batchconfig config;


   public void run() {
     Jobs job = Scheduler.listLinked.get(this);
     if (job != null && job.isState()) {
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis())
                .addString("param", job.getParam()).toJobParameters();
        try {
            JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(config.execute(job.getName()), jobParameters);
            System.out.println("Job's Status:::" + jobExecution.getStatus());
        } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException
                | JobParametersInvalidException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  }

}

@Component
public class Scheduler implements SchedulingConfigurer {


   @Override
   public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
     set();
     for (Jobs j : list) {
        MyTask th = new MyTask();
        listLinkedInverse.put(j, th);
        listLinked.put(th, j);
        taskRegistrar.addCronTask(th, j.getCron());
     }
   }

}
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.generator.config.batch.scheduler.MyTask.run(MyTask.java:39)
   at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
   at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Did you define a JobLauncher bean?

Comment: yes i tried but still returns null.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i tried this solution and it worked

```
@Component
public class Scheduler {
        @Autowired
private ApplicationContext context;


@Autowired
public static JobLauncher jobLauncher;

@Autowired
public static Batchconfig config;

@Autowired
private JobService jobService;

private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
         Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

public static Map<ScheduledFuture<Jobs>, Jobs> listLinked = new HashMap<>();
public static Map<Jobs, ScheduledFuture<Jobs>> listLinkedInverse = new HashMap<>();
List<Jobs> list;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    list = jobService.findAll();
    for (Jobs j : list) {
        if(j.isState()) {
            MyTask th = new MyTask(j);
            context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(th);
            ScheduledFuture<Jobs> jobHandler = (ScheduledFuture<Jobs>) scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(th, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            listLinkedInverse.put(j, jobHandler);
            listLinked.put(jobHandler, j);
        }

    }
}

public void launchJob(Jobs myJob){
    MyTask th = new MyTask(myJob);
    context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(th);
    ScheduledFuture<Jobs> jobHandler = (ScheduledFuture<Jobs>) scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(th, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    listLinkedInverse.put(myJob, jobHandler);
    listLinked.put(jobHandler, myJob);

}

public void cancelJob(Jobs j) {
    listLinkedInverse.get(j).cancel(true);
    listLinked.remove(listLinkedInverse.get(j));
    listLinkedInverse.remove(j);


}
}



@Component
public class MyTask extends Thread {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    private Jobs job;

    @Autowired
    private Batchconfig config;

    public MyTask() {
    }

    public MyTask(Jobs job) {
        this.job = job;
    }
    public void run() {
            JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .addString("param", job.getParam()).toJobParameters();
            try {
                JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(config.execute(job.getName()), jobParameters);
                System.out.println("Job's Status:::" + jobExecution.getStatus());
            } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException
                    | JobParametersInvalidException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `MyTask` instance is created manually (in `MyTask th = new MyTask()`) and not by Spring, hence dependency injection will not be performed and the autowired  `JobLauncher` will be null.

You need to create a bean of type `MyTask` (so that its dependencies are correctly injected) then inject it in your `Scheduler` class as a collaborator.

As a side note, this is not the ideal way to launch multiple jobs concurrently. You are creating a `JobLauncher` per thread, which in turn uses a `SyncTaskExecutor` by default. What you can do is create a single `JobLauncher` and configure it with a pool of threads to launch jobs concurrently, something like:

```
@Bean
public JobLauncher jobLauncher() {
   SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
   jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository());
   jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor()); // or use ThreadPoolTaskExecutor
   jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
   return jobLauncher;
}
```

You can find more details in the [Configuring a JobLauncher](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.2.x/reference/html/job.html#configuringJobLauncher) section of the reference documentation.

Comment: i tried this solution but i had a problem configuring the TransactionManager.